# Two Fragments in Landscape Mode Challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge, android

I did the following code challenge for a job interview.  They apparently didn't care for my solution and I'm not sure why.

What could I have done better?

Here is the challenge:

> Create a small app with the following characteristics:
>
> With the device in the portrait mode, display a fragment with a single
>   EditText instructing the user to enter his or her name. Below that,
>   display five buttons labelled "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3",
>   "Button 4" "Button 5". Tapping any of those buttons will swap in a new
>   fragment with a simple text field displaying the message, "Hello ! You
>   tapped Button 1" (or 2, and so on). Tapping the back button returns to
>   the original fragment with the five buttons.
>
> When the device is in the landscape mode, display the two fragment
>   side-by-side within the same activity, but keep the behavior described
>   above (except that the back button will exit the app as there is no
>   fragment to go back to.)
>
> [Feel free to use either the Fragment call introduced in API level 11
>   (android.app.Fragment) or the Fragment class found in the Android
>   support library (android.support.v4.app.Fragment).]

[image]

[image]

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.layout.layout_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.editText);
            editText.setText(name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.editText);
        String name = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
        outState.putString("name", name);
    }
}
```

DetailActivity.java:

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Add the Detail fragment and pass Intent Extras
        DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
        detailFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, detailFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

InputFragment.java:

```
public class InputFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.layout.fragment_input, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Create the buttons programmatically
         */
        int buttonCount = 5;
        Button[] button = new Button[buttonCount];

        // Create layout for button
        int pad = dpAsPixels(40);
        int margin = dpAsPixels(5);
        LinearLayout layoutContainer = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.ll_container);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonParam.setMargins(margin, 0, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
            button[i] = new Button(getActivity());
            button[i].setText("Button " + (i + 1));
            button[i].setLayoutParams(buttonParam);
            button[i].setPadding(pad, 0, pad, 0);

            layoutContainer.addView(button[i]);

            final String number = String.valueOf(i + 1);

            button[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.editText);
                    String name = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
                    String message = "Hello, " + name + "!  You tapped Button " + number;

                    // Rather than detect orientation, just detect if Detail fragment is currently displayed
                    View detailFrame = getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.detail);
                    boolean isDual = detailFrame != null && detailFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

                    // If in landscape mode, change the message
                    if (isDual) {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.message);
                        textView.setText(message);
                    // If in portrait mode, create an Intent
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("message", message);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private int dpAsPixels(int dp) {
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

DetailFragment.java:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.message);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String message = (args != null) ? args.getString("message") : "";

        textView.setText(message);

        return view;
    }

}
```

layout/layout_mail.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.InputFragment"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

layout-land/layout_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <fragment class="us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.InputFragment"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment class="us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.DetailFragment"
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(Full code found at github: https://github.com/jasonhartley/Fragments-Challenge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides what janos mentioned, there is one thing in your code which I really really don't like.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.editText);
String name = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
String message = "Hello, " + name + "!  You tapped Button " + number;
```

The call to `getActivity()` is not the responsibility of the fragment. **You are violating *'Tell, don't ask'***. Big time. Instead you should read up on [Communicating with Other fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

```
// Rather than detect orientation, just detect if Detail fragment is currently displayed
View detailFrame = getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.detail);
boolean isDual = detailFrame != null && detailFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

// If in landscape mode, change the message
if (isDual) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.id.message);
    textView.setText(message);
// If in portrait mode, create an Intent
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

What you are doing here is that you are doing something that is the responsibility of the activity. But you are handling it inside the fragment.

This is a bad practice. If anything, this is what I would have rejected you for.

- Avoid calling `getActivity()` in a Fragment
- Give the Fragment a callback interface which handles this. In this case, `MainActivity` should be the class implementing the interface.

Read up on [Communicating with Other fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for how to properly do this.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I knew I was probably using fragments poorly.  Using an interface for communication to and from the fragment and implementing it in the activity makes a lot more sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

#### import us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R

It's unusual and ugly that your package name `us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge` appears in many places in the source code:

> ```
> setContentView(us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R.layout.layout_main);
> ```

The common approach is to import the generated `R` file:

```
import us.jasonh.fragmentschallenge.R
```

So that you can simplify the source code and get rid of the ugly duplicated package names everywhere:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
```

Search through your code and make sure to remove all occurrences of your package name (except `import` statements).

#### Simplify

In `onActivityCreated`, you don't need to store an array of buttons.
You could just iterate from 1 to 5,
and in each cycle create a `Button`,
configure it,
including the click listener,
and add it to the view.
No need for `Button[]`.

Also, the click listener's implementation is not trivial,
embedding it inside the `onActivityCreated` method makes the method's body a bit long,
which can be flagged as a warning by static analysis tools.
It would be better to use a named private inner class instead of an anonymous class for the click listener implementation.

#### Duplicated string constants

In `onSaveInstanceState`, and when you restore from it, you save and load `"name"`.
If you write `"name"` in two places,
that's fragile,
because if you change it in one place,
you have to remember to change in the other too.
The common approach is to put this in a static constant variable:

```
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
```

And use this variable when saving and restoring "name".

The same goes for the `"message"` key you pass between the fragments.

#### Misc

Instead of this:

> ```
> String.valueOf(editText.getText())
> ```

I prefer this way:

```
editText.getText().toString()
```

For one thing, it's shorter. But maybe it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: janos, these were great pointers.  I've since implemented them all.  I guess my only remaining question is, is there a better way to approach the two-fragment thing than the way I did?  I'm still new to fragments, so I don't really know what is good form and bad form.